# Не проходит тест is_expected.to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, test-driven-development, rspec-rails

Доброго времени суток. Изучаю Ruby on Rails и возникла такая ошибка с тестами. Используется rspec-rails 3.6, capybara 2.14.4, rails 4.2.0. При выполнении тестов:

```
describe "StaticPages" do
  describe "Get home page" do
    before {visit home_path}
    it { is_expected.to have_content("home")}
    it "should have content 'home'" do
      expect(page).to have_content("home")
    end
  end
end
```

Первый тест дает ошибку, в то время как второй успешно выполняется:

```
StaticPages
Get home page
should have content "home" (FAILED - 1)
should have content 'home'
1) StaticPages Get home page should have content "home"
 Failure/Error: it{ is_expected.to have_content("home")}
   expected Get home page to respond to `has_content?`
 # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:7:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

В чем причина такого поведения и как это исправить?

Comment: а что вы ожидаете?

Comment: Ну учитывая что первый it это shortcusts второго то тест должны пройти оба. Вот текст с betterspec :On one line expectations or with implicit subject we should use is_expected.to.

BAD
it 'has 401 status code if not logged in' do
  expect(response).to respond_with 401
end
GOOD
context 'when logged out' do
  it { is_expected.to respond_with 401 }
end

Comment: что implicit subject в вашем примере?

Comment: Насколько я понимаю должен быть page.

Comment: `is_expected` == `expect(subject)`. Вариант слева советуют исключительно из семантических (смысловых) соображений.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо указать `subject`. Так как сейчас у вас в этом качестве строка `"Get home page"` - именно она идет после `describe`.

`is_expected` ссылается на `expect(subject)`.

Вот это должно починить

```
subject { page }
```

Comment: Помогло разместив непосредственно перед is.expected.to. До того как задать вопрос пробовал в блоке before, такой вариант не помогал.

Comment: нужен именно блок **subject**.